# Synchronize/Lock/GuardedBy Annotation on Lock Instances

Tags: java, concurrency, annotations, locking

I have a `ReadWriteLock` in a class and a subset of the methods start with the following common prelude:

```
rwLock.readLock().lock();
try {
    ...
} finally {
    rwLock.readLock.unlock();
}
```

and another subset of the methods utilize the same preludes but this time using `writeLock()` instead. I find this coding style quite verbose (ugly?) and am looking for an alternative way via annotations. *Are there any synchronization annotations that I can prepend to my methods/variables ala `@Synchronized(rwLock.readLock())` or `@Synchronized(rwLock.writeLock())`.*

I found out that there is a `@Lock` in Java EE, but it has two major drawbacks: 1) For such a simple requirement I do not want to move from SE to EE and 2) it does not take a `Lock` object as a parameter and uses its own `ReadWriteLock` instance.

Another alternative is to encapsulate the `Lock` into an `AutoClosable` and use `try (AutoClosable acLock = new AutoClosableLock(lock)) { ... }`, which introduces a dummy variable (`acLock`) and instantiates a new `AutoClosableLock` every time.

Comment: Considering that this is the idiom used by the java.util.concurrent classes, which have been written by the designers of the lock classes, I would think that you can't do much better.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use synchronized unless there is a really good reason not to.  In these relatively rare cases I use a Lock as you suggest.  I encapsulate the code in methods and once they work I don't look at them again.  I don't feel all the code needs to look beautiful esp low level code (something rather hard to do in Java efficiently)

Comment: Quite often method accesses are read-only and there rarely comes an update to the class fields. Hence, using `synchronized` will be unfair and regular read operations will be blocked unnecessarily.

Comment: @VolkanYazıcı This is a good example of when you should use RedWriteLock.  However, unless this hit very often, you might find there is little performance difference and simpler code is more desirable.  For example, I wouldn't change it unless I had seen it was an issue in a proifler.  Often, if you don't measure a performance requirement, you are just guessing.